# Ça fait super longtemps qu’on m’a pas posé la question

Tags: grammaire

The following:

1. Ça fait super longtemps qu’on m’a pas posé la question [quel âge as-tu].

was a translation of:

2. It's been a long time since someone has asked me that [how old I am].

You'll notice that the word 'pas' is found in the French but 'not' is not found in the English.  So suppose every day someone asks you how old you are, then one fine day no one asks you that question and you say to yourself:

3. It's been a long time since someone has not asked me that [how old I am]

How would express that in French without uttering 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's been a long time since someone has not asked me that [how old I am]
>
> How would express that in French without uttering 1?

As you noticed, in French, *cela fait longtemps que* in that sense is most of the time followed by a negative form. But in your example, there is a second negative since we're talking about the absence of something.
The closer together the two negatives, the more clunky and complicated the sentence. We tend to avoid:

> ❌ Cela fait longtemps qu'on ne m'a *pas pas* posé cette question.

The further away, the smoother:

> Je ne me souviens pas de la dernière fois où on ne m'a pas demandé ça.

although the second *pas* is easy to miss. You could also use a simple affirmative form which is always clearer, but you have to make explicit the fact induced from the original sentence, i.e. that it didn't happen today:

> Cela fait bien longtemps qu'on me pose cette question à chaque discussion. Mais pas aujourd'hui.

Another possibility:

> Ça fait longtemps que quelqu'un ne s'est pas abstenu de me poser cette question.

Answer (score 0):

1 is quite familar. "*il y a bien longtemps qu'on ne m'a pas posé la question*" is more formal.

"*La dernière fois que l'on m'a posé cette question, ça remonte à loin*" is an alternative.

Comment: thanks, i appreciate that.

Comment: Actually, on second thought.  Wouldn't your translation be back-translated into: "the last time someone asked me that question was a long time ago," which is consistent with 2 and contradicts 3?

Comment: @bobsmith76 Indeed, it can't mean (3) despite the negative. Your original sentence really is just a paraphrase (an idiomatic paraphrase) equivalent to "A lot of time has passed in which no one has asked me the question."

Comment: @bobsmith76 If I translated *il y a bien longtemps qu'on ne m'a pas posé la question*, I'd say: "I haven't been asked that question (for ages/ for quite some time - or whatever)" let's keep in mind that *on* is one of the ways we translate an English passive voice into French.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

À l'oral, surtout familier, le "ne" de la négation est souvent absent contrairement à l'écrit. La phrase correcte reste "Ça fait super longtemps qu’on ne m’a pas posé la question." [La question m'a été posée récemment.]

Je pense que les réactions précédentes se rapportent à la phrase "Ça fait super longtemps qu’on m’a posé la question." qui est aussi valable [La question m'a été posée il y a longtemps.]